# sudo as another user that contains current user string in username

Tags: sudo, sudoers

Let's say there are 100 users in the system:

- msmith
- bdole
- agrant
- . . .

Is there a way to write a generic sudoers rule to allow each of these users to execute commands as another user, where the target user contains original username in the name, and ends with a specific string? (Without having to hard-core a separate rule for each individual user)

Such as:

- User msmith can run commands as msmith_test (as that user only)
- User bdole can run commands as bdole_test (as that user only)
- User agrant can run commands as agrant_test (as that user only)
- . . .

Something LIKE the following, and I understand that sudoers doesn't see/can't possibly use ${LOGNAME} shell variable:

```
+testgroup  TEST_SERVER_LIST = (${LOGNAME}_test) ALL
```

Comment: How is this related to programming? It is about system configurarion.

Comment: I thought about that, but I saw a ton of other questions regarding sudo. Any suggestions where this question should go instead?